# Overwrote Windows with Linux, how can I recover data?

Tags: linux, windows, data-recovery

While installing Ubuntu 11.10 (ext4) I accidentally chose a wrong partition and it overwrote my Windows 2003 installation (ntfs). How can I recover files?

So far I tried photoRec and it recovered some. Testdisk refuses to recover the entire partition, perhaps because it would have to recover a partition it is running from. Should I try making a liveCD "rescue disk" and run `testdisk` from there? Is there any software that could help me? Or should I install Windows again on another partition and try recovery with some Windows software?

Comment: Recovery is a black art, the only security is to backup, regularly. And *double-check* your partitioning when doing _any_ potentially destructive operation.

Answer (score 12):

Your overwritten files are lost forever from that partition. Restore them from backup.

Running Testdisk from a live CD might help a little; use the Testdisk live CD, which has a number of recovery tools. But be aware that recovery quickly gets difficult; it'll be quicker to recover your own data from backups, and to reinstall any third-party software from where you got it in the first place (and you will have to redo a clean installation of Windows itself).

Answer (score 1):

You should also try Foremost and Scalpel. Here you can find an excellent article that explains clearly how to do it:
http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/15761/recover-data-like-a-forensics-expert-using-an-ubuntu-live-cd/